# java mouse question ACM packages program and graphics

Tags: java, acm-java-libraries

I have 2 classes, A and B. A is a subclass of Program (i.e. acm.program.*) and B is a subclass of [`GCanvas`](http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/GCanvas.html)(i.e. [`acm.graphics.*`](http://jtf.acm.org/javadoc/student/acm/graphics/package-frame.html)).

In Class A  I have an init  method which initiates and adds class B.

In Class B  I have 2 things I want to achieve: I want to respond to changes in the window size and mouse clicks.  I can achieve the window size changes by adding component listeners.  I cannot achieve the mouse clicking events.

Now, I know how I would do it in a situation where I didn't care about responding to window re-sizing.  I would have 1 class, extend GraphicsProgram, and add mouselisteners and not have any problem.

What is your recommendation?  How do I have these two events handlers exist concurrently within a single GCanvas?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a GCanvas is, from the documentation, an awt Component, you can always call this class [`addMouseListener()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29) or [`addMouseMotionListener()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseMotionListener%28java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener%29) method and do what you want with mouse events.

Comment: If you think this answer is the correct one **don't** say thank you, but rather accept it using the check at left side (just below the up/down arrows).